# How to take an absolute value or modulus of z?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, modules

let's assume the :

$$z=\frac{e^{(-jc)}}{(a+jb)}$$
I would like to take the absolute value of z.
I started with multiplication z with $\frac{(a-jb)}{(a-jb)}$ and got:
$$abs\frac{e^{(-jc)}}{(a+jb)}=\frac{e^{(-jc)}(a-jb)}{(a^2+b^2)}$$
Then:
$$\frac{e^{(-jc)}(a-jb)*e^{(jc)}}{(a^2-b^2)e^{(jc)}}=\frac{(a-jb)}{(a^2+b^2)e^{(jc)}}$$
Should I repeat the calculations or I made something wrong?

**edit 1:**

$(a-jb)(a+jb)=a^2+b^2$

**edit 2:**

$ abs(e^{(-jc)})=1$

$ abs(z)=\frac{(a-jb)}{(a^2+b^2)e^{(jc)}}$

what should i do with $(a-jb)$? Or will be it $(a^2+b^2)$?

Comment: Are you using 'j' as a symbol for iota(i.e. $\sqrt{-1}$)?

Comment: @Crazyformaths yes

Comment: Multiplication with $a-jb$ gives $a^2+b^2$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $w=re^{j\theta}$ for $r,\theta\in\Bbb R$, then $|w|=|r|$.

Comment: This is assuming $j^2=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that
$$
\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right|=\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}
$$
If $c$ is real, then $|e^{-jc}|=|\cos c+j\sin c|=1$. So you have
$$
\left|\frac{e^{-jc}}{a+jb}\right|=\frac{1}{|a+jb|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
$$